# Wordpress Installation not getting completed

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to install a wordpress in my local machine, I am using wamp server, when i tried to install the wordpress, after the screen of "Information needed" I can not see the complete installation, it stopped on this link

```
http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/install.php?step=2
```

in the database there are 11 table created.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Please add [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provide much information what exactly is the problem, maybe [this article](http://www.wpwebhost.com/install-wordpress-on-wampserver/)  might help you.

It is a step by step tutorial on how to install WordPress on WampServer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and what solve my problem was setting **90** instead of 30 for **max_execution_time** in php.ini, like :

> max_execution_time = 90