# Wordpress installation not get completed in Wamp server

Tags: wordpress, wamp

i have installed wamp server on windows 8, and trying to install wordpress on it, but while installing it could not complete it. it's showing me the error like

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php?step=2
```

after that the process stops.

Screenshot:

[image]

I had refered the question on [Wordpress Installation not getting completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729658/wordpress-installation-not-getting-completed) but it could not help me.

Can anyone sort this out.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress is normally a breeze to install.

Have you read this [Famous 5-Minute Install](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress)  and the pre-requisites on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I resolved it after finding this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/installation-hangs-on-step-2-after-creating-basic-dbs-without-admin-user?replies=16

so i just edited the php.ini file as suggested in that post (increased the max_execution_time) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The fix for me was that I needed to include the port onto the localhost when assigning the database host.

Like: localhost:8080.